# Non-linear model fit doesn't like my weights

Tags: fitting

I have 250  ordered pairs of numbers I wish to fit using a polynomial with 5 terms.

dataList={{90.5125000, 1001.3813546}, {91.57125000,977.380533274897744}, {92.5698486328125000, 966.2342342}, and so on}.

I have a weights list of 250 values in a list like

dataWeights={0.85836772180041806, 0.577296547023891154, 0.2, 0.686562524674504328, 1, 0.23434, and so on}

When I try to put the Weights-> dataWeights into the fitting equation, computing aborts with no error message. All my variables turn blue.

Anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

```
NonlinearModelFit[dataList, a ((x/150.0))^-2 + b ((x/150.0))^-1 + c ((x/150.0))^1.0  + d ((x/150.0))^2 + e(interpfn[x]), {a, b, c, d, e}, x]
```

runs fine, but

```
NonlinearModelFit[dataList, a ((x/150.0))^-2 + b ((x/150.0))^-1 +  c ((x/150.0))^1.0 + d ((x/150.0))^2 + e(interpfn[x]), {a, b, c, d, e}, x, Weights-> dataWeights]
```

does not run

The interp function of x is simply an interpolation of a list that was made into an interpolation function. That list is not monotonic, if that matters - resembles about 1 to 2 cycles of a sine wave.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better if you find a way to provide the data you are using. (E.g. through [https://pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com).)

Comment: also  see if you can reproduce the problem with a smaller set of data.  The variables turning blue indicates your kernel has crashed, btw.

Comment: I will try this with a smaller data set to see if it doesn't like some of the weights, or if a combination of the weights is causing issues. Perhaps a computer reboot may help as well. I've had kernel crashes before that were fixed with a windows 10 reboot.

Comment: notice you have a term with no exponent and then one with `^1.` which are effectively redundant. Not that it should cause a crash, but you might try getting rid of one. (and maybe you want a constant term..)

Comment: It still crashes even with only 26 points weight list = {0.9987527, 0.99976478704084643, 0.999722848903, \
0.9993126, 0.9997489, 0.99974733307567956, \
0.98364314121504532, 0.99878819613270000, 0.99972987911051269, \
0.99919462417872860, 0.92152614146854338, 0.99960687021314616, \
0.99885219400497854, 0.99958609168318560, 0.807542606375684133, \
0.358750462322291623, 0.99949217272776386, 0.99962266189591619, \
0.99880149439187476, 0.99953788549367709, 0.99907244642256050, \
0.99911067891768793, 0.87373801598284525, 0.87409790012176219, \
0.98225430427248133, 0.515316685575128931}

Comment: I'm just repeating the suggestion to provide a complete set of data.  How about the 26 data points along with the 26 weights you give above?  (And that's data in the question and not in the comments.)

Comment: OK - I'll have to sanitize the data, then edit the question to add them.